# How is selling the use of a house not usury but selling the use of wine, separately from the wine, is?

Tags: morality, thomas-aquinas, thomism, usury

St. Thomas Aquinas, [*Summa Theologica* II-II q. 78 a. 1](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS078.html#SSQ78A1THEP1) co., says that usury is to sell the use of a consumable good separately from the consumable good itself:

> To take usury for money lent is unjust in itself, because this is to sell what does not exist, and this evidently leads to inequality which is contrary to justice. In order to make this evident, we must observe that there are certain **things the use of which consists in their consumption**: thus we consume wine when we use it for drink and we consume wheat when we use it for food. Wherefore in such like things the use of the thing must not be reckoned apart from the thing itself, and whoever is granted the use of the thing, is granted the thing itself and for this reason, to lend things of this kin is to transfer the ownership. Accordingly if a man wanted to sell wine separately from the use of the wine, he would be selling the same thing twice, or he would be selling what does not exist, wherefore he would evidently commit a sin of injustice. On like manner he commits an injustice who lends wine or wheat, and asks for double payment, viz. one, the return of the thing in equal measure, the other, the price of the use, which is called usury.
>
> On the other hand, there are **things the use of which does n̲o̲t̲ consist in their consumption**: thus to use a house is to dwell in it, not to destroy it. Wherefore in such things both may be granted: for instance, one man may hand over to another the ownership of his house while reserving to himself the use of it for a time, or vice versa, he may grant the use of the house, while retaining the ownership. For this reason a man may lawfully make a charge for the use of his house, and, besides this, revendicate the house from the person to whom he has granted its use, as happens in renting and letting a house.

But that explanation makes no sense to me. Just because the use of wine consists in its destruction, I do not see how this implies that the sale of the use of wine also implies the sale of the property itself.

I see no significant difference between using a house as a dwelling and using wine for drinking. If the sale of the use of the house can be separated from the sale of the property itself, then the sale of the use of the wine can also be separated from the sale of the property itself.

Comment: I think a better question is "why is ursury _not_ a sin?"

Comment: Potential answerers: here's [a great resource](https://www.superflumina.org/usury_1.html)

Comment: How can one sell wine which has been used?

Comment: The edited question title doesn't make sense. Aquinas isn't saying that selling wine is usury nor that selling the use of the house isn't. He's contrasting different types of goods and defining usury as a sin because of what type of good it is and how the selling is accounted.

Comment: @eques Yes, I know St. Thomas isn't saying that, but GuilhermedeSouza seems to think St. Thomas's argument against usury implies that.

Comment: I don't think GuilhermedeSouza equates those with usury only that he doesn't see a difference between those types of goods

Comment: @eques, "How can one sell wine which has been used?" You really don't want me to answer that.  But it's a valid point; if wine has been "used", it's been transmuted beyond its further use as wine. Not so a house, which can be inhabited for a while and may be substantially unaltered afterward. (And even if changes are made, it's normally still usable *as a house*.)

Comment: @Matthew it was meant as a rhetorical question to counter what OP claimed to not to see as different between wine and a house

Comment: @eques, yes, which I "answered" with a joke. And expanded upon. My comment was not meant to disagree with yours.

Comment: @eques So can you sell the use AND ownership itself before the person drinks the wine?

Comment: @GuilhermedeSouza the point isn't so much before drinking but that you cannot sell ownership apart from use.

Comment: @eques And I still don't understand why you can't.

Comment: Because the use of wine results in the destruction of the wine so there's nothing left to own.

Comment: @eques But before drinking the wine, the wine still exists.

Comment: Of course -- but the point is use of the wine destroys the wine so if you sold the use but not ownership, you would be selling the ability for X to drink the wine while Y owned it. Once X has drank it, Y doesn't own anything. Hence the ownership cannot be separated from the use in sale. In contrast a house where the use of the house doesn't eliminate the house afterwards.

Comment: @eques Again, you argument argument can work if I drank the wine, but it doesn't work if I did not drink. If the wine has been consumed then there is nothing left to sell, but if has not been consumed I do not see the reason why I cannot sell the substance after I have sold the use.

Comment: @eques "To hand over a mutuum is ipso facto to give total ownership of it, i.e. to renounce any claim to the good and therefore any title to charging for it." I simply don't see the logic here. WHY handing over a mutuum necessary gives you TOTAL owership?

Comment: @GuilhermedeSouza if you sell the use (= to drink) to someone, by their exercising of what they have acquired, they destroy the ownership that was either retained by you or you attempted to sell to another person. Since their use destroys the ownership, it cannot be sold apart from the ownership. Whether the person does actually drink the wine is irrelevant. The point is that you sold the ability for them to drink it.

Comment: Aquinas was never a landlord.

Answer (score 2):

St. Thomas Aquinas gets of a lot of things right, but on this matter I believe he is simply incorrect.

His argument has two parts. First, it is only okay to charge for the use of something when ownership can be separated from the use, such as with renting a house. If something is consumed (destroyed) by the use, then the ownership cannot be separated, and therefore it's not okay to charge for the use separately from the thing; you'd be double-dipping, and that's not good.

I don't necessarily disagree with that idea. I'm not fully convinced of it, either, but I'd love to see the principal applied to certain software licensing regimes, for example.

I also want to point out this doesn't strictly eliminate money-lending as a potential business venture. It would be okay under this rule to, say, lend $100 in exchange for receiving $110 when the loan is repaid (the balance plus $10 in reasonable profit). What this principal says is the charge for a monetary loan should be fixed up front, rather than grow the longer the loan (use) lasts.

---

But there is still the second part of the argument (money is consumed in the use), and here is where I need to pose a question: *which type of thing is money, really?*

Let's say I take small loan to buy food: say I visit a restaurant and pay by credit card. Clearly the money the was consumed by the purchase, and very soon so is the food. It seems like Mr Aquinas is right. But what if I take a larger loan to start a business? The business is still there after I spend the money, and (hopefully) very soon so is the money.

Economically, we say money is **fungible**: that is, it is easily converted from one thing to another. There are many things one can purchase with money that are also **durable** and themselves (perhaps somewhat less) fungible. So I can take a loan to purchase (or rent) a thing in order to perform some service, then sell the thing to get the money back, and return the "same" money to lender.

That is, money *can* be consumed from the use, but it is not *certain* to be.

Now lets go back to restaurant example, and add another wrinkle. Let's say my bank balance is $0; I have no money of my own at this particular moment. However, I do have a steady job and am expecting a paycheck tomorrow, and we'll also say my current broke state is for expected reasons that don't particularly concern me.

This helps us look at the nature of this small credit card loan in terms of a *time shift*, as well. Even for this most ephemeral use of the money, I still only need or want it *for a particular moment in time*, and then I return it, perhaps as soon as the next day. Even here, we see the loan was ultimately about use over time, rather than consumption.

---

The nature of any loan, then, is the borrower must return to the lender the full the value of what was borrowed, and on top of this the lender may reasonably charge a fee for the **use** of the borrowed money, to make it worth his effort and inconvenience. The longer the duration of the loan, the longer the lender is deprived of the use of the money himself (to make other loans, for example), and therefore it is justifiable this fee can also be time-based.

Where we should take exception is with **EXCESSIVE** usuary.

---

For fun, let's further look at a basic idea for limiting excessive usury.

What if we had legal limits in place to prevent finance charges beyond the value of the initial principal of any loan? The moment interest and fees have reach the value of the original principal, any outstanding balance is still owed, but the lender no longer has the ability to tack on additional charges.

This seems like a great baseline protection for borrowers. It might even still allow excessive usury, but as a final backstop it's better than nothing.

But now let's think deeper. How does one arrive at this situation? Either you agreed to (and signed for) a loan with excessive usury built in, or you failed at some point to meet your repayment obligations for the original loan, allowing the use fees (interested) to pile up. At this point, the lender could reasonably argue you are extending the loan to use periods, which justify new charges.

I think doubling over the original principal is still excessive, but at some point holding onto the balance is depriving the lender of their property, and there needs to be a penalty. Perhaps a better idea is that at this point interest can no longer compound.

Comment: "_Where we should take exception is with EXCESSIVE usuary._" No. Benedict XIV writes in [_Vix Pervenit_](https://www.papalencyclicals.net/ben14/b14vixpe.htm): "any gain which exceeds the amount given is illicit and usurious."

Comment: This doesn't seem to actually counter the quoted part of Aquinas. For one, you don't establish that the degree of fee is the essence of usury (or rather that Aquinas assumes degree is necessary for it to be sin). Incidentally, it's especially bizarre to refer to Aquinas as Mister since he's a dead, sainted, Italian Dominican friar.

Comment: @eques "_the degree of fee is the essence of usury_" No; "**any** gain" on a _mutuum_ contract is usurious.

Comment: @Geremia I'm aware. I was countering the claims of Joel. That is, for his argument (distinguishing excessive usury as a sin from usury in general) to be valid, either Aquinas would have assumed that all degree is too much (and hence in theory a small degree might be not a sin) OR that the degree of the fee is the essence of usury. However, Aquinas' argument is not one of degree but substance/category; the way the gain is calculated is per se usury and hence sinful

Comment: Fwiw, my answer does not begin to talk about degree (excessive) until after it has dismantled the argument separate from that concept.

Comment: You correctly point to the question of what type of good money is and then fail to completely counter the argument that money is consumed because you simply assume that because it's fungible it is not always consumed or rather because something durable can be sold again for the same amount of money, the money wasn't consumed. What if you had traded some quantity of wine for some durable good? Couldn't you sell the item later in exchange for a similar quantity of wine? Does that mean wine isn't consumable in Aquinas's distinctions?

Answer (score 1):

Catholic legal professor and usury expert [Brian McCall](https://works.bepress.com/brian_mccall/) describes the difference between

1. goods consumed/destroyed in their first use

and

2. goods whose use does not result in their destruction,

in [*To Build the City of God: Living as Catholics in a Secular Age*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7017) (2017), ch. 4 "The Details of Economics: Money, Debt, Just Price, and Usury", § "Usury: What Is It? How Do We Avoid It? Why Do Our Shepherds Ignore It?":

> To discern what Scripture and Tradition have taught, we need to define some terms. This is somewhat tedious but necessary in this complicated area. To begin, we will start with some statements from the last major papal document that focused exclusively on usury, [*Vix Pervenit*](https://www.papalencyclicals.net/ben14/b14vixpe.htm) [[Latin](http://www.domus-ecclesiae.de/magisterium/vix-pervenit.html)] of Benedict XIV [in 1745]. The pope writes, "The nature of the sin called usury has its proper place and origin in a *loan* [*mutuum*] contract." [*Peccati genus illud, quod usura vocatur, quodque in contractu mutui propriam suam sedem et locum habet*] He continues, "any *gain* which exceeds the amount he [the lender] gave is illicit and usurious." [*Omne propterea hujusmodi lucrum, quod sortem superet, illicitum, et usurarium est.*] The two highlighted terms are critical to this summary of the doctrine.  If a particular transaction is not a loan, then any gain cannot be usury (although it may be licit or illicit as a result of a moral principal other than usury, as when, for example, a merchant sells a product for more than its just price). Secondly, only "gain" is usury. We need to examine carefully what these two terms signify.
>
> In modern law and speech, the word "loan" has a broad meaning. It can be used to describe when a person gives money to another to buy food or medical care and expects repayment of that money at another date. It can refer to an investor who provides capital to a business for a time and expects the return of his capital and a profit. Further, it can describe when a person gives another a piece of property (like a car) to be used for a while and requires the return of that same property. The Roman law had distinct terms to identify all of these transactions, which are now signified by our word "loan." Since most of the examples of the infallible teaching of the Church on usury use these Roman law terms, we need to understand that the law of usury only applied to those situations designated by the Roman word for "loan" (*mutuum*) and not the modern term.
>
> The *mutuum* involved the transfer of ownership of a fungible good that was consumed in first use and required that the borrower return at a later time property of the same kind and quantity provided to him. This definition only covers the first example we cited above. The other examples were identified by other terms, such as *societas*, *census commodatum*, and *conductio locatio re*. One could not commit usury when engaging in these other transactions (again, other sins were possible but not usury).
>
> Before progressing, we need to understand the concept of "consumed in first use." The *mutuum* only applied to the transfer and retransfer of this type of property. It is something that cannot be used without its destruction or loss. Tangible property can be divided into three groups of things: (1) those that can be used without their total loss, (2) those that can only be used by their total loss, and (3) those things which have different possible uses, some of which consume the thing and some of which do not. A house can be lived in and not destroyed. Wine cannot be used (for drinking or cooking) without consuming it. A potato can be used without consuming it (for example, by planting it as a seed potato) or by consuming it (eating it). From about 325 through the fourteenth century, money was thought to be exclusively or almost always in the second category of things that are consumed in first use. Due to the expansion of commerce, more opportunities to use money in a productive way (like the seed potato) became common. Many theologians began to consider whether money was actually in the third category of things that can be used in first use or used productively. Money could be used without consuming it completely (like planting a seed potato to grow more potatoes).
>
> The next important concept in the pope's statement is "gain." The sin of usury occurs when a lender of a fungible thing consumed in first use requires that he be put in a better position than he was in before the loan. It is licit to require equality in position. Now we must distinguish gain from compensation for a loss. If a man steals my car and crashes it, he then is obligated to give me a new car of similar quality in restitution. I do not gain; I merely return to my original position. The Roman law called the payment to compensate for loss *quod interest* or the "difference." The original meaning of our word "interest" was not payment of gain for a loan but payment in compensation for a loss. For example, Marcus borrows 100 ducats from Linus and promises to pay it back in two months. Linus needs the money back in two months to pay his son's tuition at the university.  Linus pays the money back two months late, and as a result Linus has to pay a ten ducat fine for paying tuition late. Marcus should pay Linus ten ducats in "interest" to compensate him for that loss. This payment is not usury, as it is not a payment for the use (consummation of money) but merely compensation for the harm done by not returning the money when agreed.

See also his talk "[The Principal and Gross Injustice of Usury](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q9dJ3ojv2iA)".

Comment: The strange thing with the quote is the example of the potato because unless I'm mistaken when one plants a potato to use as a seed potato, the original potato is consumed (it no longer exists). It is not like a car or house where it can be used.

Comment: @eques A potato is one of "(3) those things which have different possible uses".

Comment: I was able to read the quote. My point is that it doesn't make sense. Consume doesn't mean "to eat" in the division of goods; it means used up.

Comment: @eques A consumable good is "something that cannot be used without its destruction or loss."

Comment: " without consuming it (for example, by planting it as a seed potato)" and pray tell, in what way is a potato not "destroyed or lost" by being planted as a seed potato? Just because you aim to get more potatoes doesn't mean the original potato isn't lost.

Comment: Additionally, you keep saying things as though I didn't  read the answer. I literally defined what consumable meant in my previous comment and you only provide an equivalent definition.

Comment: @eques I don't understand why you say: "_Consume doesn't mean 'to eat' in the division of goods_".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141105/discussion-between-geremia-and-eques).

Comment: I still don't understand.

Comment: @GuilhermedeSouza A house is not a good destroyed in its first use; its use can be separated from it and sold separately. Wine's use is inseparably bound up with its consumption; wine is meant to be drunk. To sell wine with the proviso it can't be consumed is against the nature of wine.

Comment: @Geremia Killing animals and plants goes against their nature.

Comment: @Geremia And I still don't see why destruction of the wine matters. I don't see why this is different from using a house.

Comment: @GuilhermedeSouza "_Killing animals and plants goes against their nature._" God created animals and plants for us to eat: [Gen. 9:3](https://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=1&ch=9&l=3-#x):  every thing that moveth, and liveth shall be meat for you: even as the green herbs have I delivered them all to you".

Comment: @GuilhermedeSouza "_I still don't see why destruction of the wine matters._" Wine can only be used in a matter that results in its total consumption/destruction. A house can be used without destroying it.

Comment: @Geremia Death is an evil for the animal/vegetal nature that is being imposed on them. The fact that I do nothing against my human nature (the perfect using the imperfect) does not change the fact that evil is being inflicted upon them.

Comment: @Geremia Again, why does it matter that the wine will be destructed?

Comment: @Geremia "To hand over a mutuum is ipso facto to give total ownership of it, i.e. to renounce any claim to the good and therefore any title to charging for it." I simply don't see the logic here. WHY handing over a mutuum necessary gives you TOTAL owership?

Comment: @GuilhermedeSouza "_why does it matter that the wine will be destructed?_" That's like asking: "Why does it matter that I'm a human?" It's the nature of the wine to be consumed as a drink; that's the end/purpose of wine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141366/discussion-between-geremia-and-guilherme-de-souza).

Answer (score 0):

According to the Bible, usury (charging interest) is not a sin unless one requires this of a fellow believer (fellow Israelite).

> If thou lend money to any of my people that is poor by thee, thou
> shalt not be to him as an usurer, neither shalt thou lay upon him
> usury. (Exodus 22:25, KJV)
>
> <sup>36</sup> Take thou no usury of him, or increase: but fear thy
> God; that thy brother may live with thee. <sup>37</sup> Thou shalt not give him thy money upon usury, nor lend him thy victuals for increase. (Exodus
> 25:36-37, KJV)

Notice the words "my people" and "thy brother."  Compare those passages with the following that expands the message to others.

> <sup>19</sup> Thou shalt not lend upon usury to thy brother; usury of
> money, usury of victuals, usury of any thing that is lent upon usury:
> <sup>20</sup> **Unto a stranger thou mayest lend upon usury;** but unto
> thy brother thou shalt not lend upon usury: that the LORD thy God may
> bless thee in all that thou settest thine hand to in the land whither
> thou goest to possess it. (Deuteronomy 23:19-20, KJV)

A little thought might suffice to understand the reason usury is allowed for the stranger.  All that a believer owns is understood to belong to God, and the believer is just a steward of his Lord's resources.  Lending to a stranger means those resources are, for the time, tied up, and are not directly prospering the Lord's work.  The primary recompense for this loss is in the usury received back later, which can then be invested in God's work.  A secondary recompense might come in the form of the witness, with respect to kindness in lending, that may attract the unbeliever to a knowledge of God.  Beyond these goals, however, there is little benefit to lending to an unbeliever (a stranger); and the enemies of God would like very much to occupy all the Lord's resources.

Aquinas' logic is a bit convoluted.  I understand what he is saying, but I disagree with it.  He is essentially saying that for a consumable, to lend it is to give it, because it will be consumed.  To ask for an equal measure back is the only way in which it could be lent.  But to ask for double back is to require that which was not given--and to his mind, this is unjust.

I disagree, however, because when one goes without for a period of time, one loses the benefit that might have been conferred by the thing lent for that time, and the usury would be to cover this loss.  Consider the rationale for demanding at the law reparations for "loss of consortium."  Even being deprived for a period of time can result in tangible effects.  Thus it is with lending--during the period something or someone is lent, the lender is deprived of that which is lent, and usury is the price for that.

An interesting question would be whether or not Aquinas intends to be addressing believers only, or everyone.  In any case, Biblically speaking, there is a difference between charging believers or unbelievers.

Comment: In what way is this a Thomistic or answer based upon Aquinas?